# Setting relative output path of PDB files when producing VS 2008 project files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cmake

Has anyone been able to modify the destination folder of PDB files using CMake when generating VS 2008 project files to make them relative paths?  It seems they always end up using an absolute path and I can't see anyway to easily modify this.

As an example one of the pdb files which gets generated is ending up at...

> E:/3dconcert-builder/dt_src_REL-2.3.0/lib/Debug/../../bin/dtAnimd.pdb

Whereas I need it to end up at...

> ../../bin/dtAnimd.pdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you need that, and it makes a lot of sense.

Unfortunately the CMake developers don't get it:
http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=9042

"Relative path is not really supported any more..."

I attached a a patch and precompiled Windows cmake.exe executable based on CMake 2.8 that works at above issue.

Comment: Great thanks for the reply Erwin!  Unfortunately (or fortunately?) I am no longer working at the company where this was an issue but thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=9042, the issue was fixed after the Erwin's answer, so CMake should now support the relative .pdb paths as desired. I have not personally verified this.